# Angular2 RC5: repeated import in component and router file

Tags: angular

I created a NgModule like below, but in my SomeComponent, I still need to include SomeService, otherwise, it will give an error. Is that the correct way? Same as routing file, I need to import the components that already imported in NgModule.

```
@NgModule({
    imports:      [ CommonModule, SharedModule ],
    declarations: [ SomeComponent ],
    providers:    [ SomeService ]
})

export class TestModule { }
```

in SomeComponent:

```
    import { SomeService } from "./some.service";

    export class SomeComponent {
        constructor(private _someService: SomeService) {
           this._comService.xxx
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct. Importing gives you access to the properties and methods of the service class, and including a reference to it in the constructor parameters tells Angular to retrieve an instance of it.

The only thing you (usually) don't want to do is list the service as a provider inside of the components you want to use it in. Since it is already listed in the providers array in the module decorator, listing it as a provider elsewhere will create separate instances.

See [Angular NgModule docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html)

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. You will still need to do the import. You just don't need to declare providers and directives all over the place.